# How to iterate inner objects in a defined object in Scala

Tags: scala

My question is how to iterate inner objects in a defined object in Scala using Scala `reflection package`?

```
object Units {

    val values = CITIZEN :: WORKER :: Nil // I need something reflectional to list all of the case objects

    case object CITIZEN extends Population
    case object WORKER extends Population
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but I'd suggest using macros (compile-time reflection) over runtime reflection, for the sake of both performance and (more importantly) type safety.

Here's a quick implementation with macros:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object MacroUtils {
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context

  def values = macro MacroUtils.values_impl
  def values_impl(c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._

    val objs = c.enclosingClass.collect {
      case ModuleDef(mods, name, _) if mods hasFlag Flag.CASE => Ident(name)
    }

    c.Expr[List[Any]](
      Apply(Select(reify(List).tree, newTermName("apply")), objs.toList)
    )
  }
}

trait Population

object Units {
  val values = MacroUtils.values
  case object CITIZEN extends Population
  case object WORKER extends Population
}
```

And then, for example:

```
scala> val populations: List[Population] = Units.values
populations: List[Population] = List(CITIZEN, WORKER)
```

Note that the compiler knows that the list of case objects can be statically typed as a list of populations.

Comment: There is a problem, macro implementation must be in statically accessible object in `def values = macro MacroUtils.values_impl`

Comment: Did you move the definition of the `values` method? It works for me exactly as pasted above.

Comment: Yes, I had a mistake in the Units object

Comment: The process takes only one millisecond

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but here it is:

```
object Units {

    val values = CITIZEN :: WORKER :: Nil

    trait Population

    case object CITIZEN extends Population

    case object WORKER extends Population

    val reflectionValues = {
        import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
        val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
        val objects = ru.typeOf[Units.type].declarations.filter(_.isModule)
        objects.map(o => mirror.reflectModule(o.asModule).instance.asInstanceOf[Population]).toList
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        assert(values == reflectionValues)
    }
}
```